# Como criar um ListView com ação de delete

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm

Olá,
Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma listview na qual tenha opção de remover aquele item da lista. Estou trabalhando com MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se isso resolve:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
            <ListView x:Name="listaProdutos" ItemSelected="listaProdutos_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Preco}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Este é o código completo

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        DataService dataService;
        List<Produto> produtos;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataService = new DataService();
            AtualizaDados();
        }

        async void AtualizaDados()
        {
            produtos = await dataService.GetProdutosAsync();
            listaProdutos.ItemsSource = produtos.OrderBy(item => item.Nome).ToList();
        }

        private async void btnAdicionar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPageModal());
            if (Valida())
            {
                Produto novoProduto = new Produto
                {
                    Nome = txtNome.Text.Trim(),
                    Categoria = txtCategoria.Text.Trim(),
                    Preco = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text)
                };
                try
                {
                    await dataService.AddProdutoAsync(novoProduto);
                    //LimpaProduto();
                    AtualizaDados();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Dados inválidos...", "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void OnAtualizar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Valida())
            {
                try
                {
                    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                    Produto produtoAtualizar = (Produto)mi.CommandParameter;
                    produtoAtualizar.Nome = txtNome.Text;
                    produtoAtualizar.Categoria = txtCategoria.Text;
                    produtoAtualizar.Preco = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);
                    await dataService.UpdateProdutoAsync(produtoAtualizar);
                    //LimpaProduto();
                    AtualizaDados();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", "Dados inválidos...", "OK");
            }
        }

        private async void OnDeletar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
                Produto produtoDeletar = (Produto)mi.CommandParameter;
                await dataService.DeletaProdutoAsync(produtoDeletar);
                //LimpaProduto();
                AtualizaDados();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        private bool Valida()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNome.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCategoria.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPreco.Text))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void listaProdutos_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var produto = e.SelectedItem as Produto;

            txtNome.Text = produto.Nome;
            txtCategoria.Text = produto.Categoria;
            txtPreco.Text = produto.Preco.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema de remover um item da listview com a  solução proposta pelo @pnet.

Comment: Se puder marcar a resposta, agradecemos para não ficar um post já resolvido e sem estar marcado. Bom que resolveu.

Comment: Obrigada pela dica e ajuda, como sou novata por aqui não sabia disso. Já marquei a resposta.